# Why do I get a segmentation fault on launch with this code?

Tags: sdl

I am currently writing a pong clone in C++ with SDL on top. Currently, I have hit a roadblock. If I add a new variable, my game won't launch, and will give "segmentation fault" in the debug terminal.

When I comment out a variable, the following code gives no errors, but otherwise, it just returns "Segmentation Fault" on the debug terminal after flashing the frame the game would normally appear in.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdlib>
#else
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#else
#include <SDL.h>
#endif
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_framerate.h"


#include "checkcol.h"

Uint8 *keystates = SDL_GetKeyState( NULL );

int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
    // initialize SDL video
    if ( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "Unable to init SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        return 1;
    }

    atexit(SDL_Quit);// make sure SDL cleans up before exit

    // create a new window
    SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 16,SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
    if ( !screen )
    {
        printf("Unable to set 640x480 video: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }


    SDL_Surface* left = IMG_Load("left.png");
    SDL_Surface* right = IMG_Load("right.png");
    SDL_Surface* ball = IMG_Load("ball.png");

    if (!left||!right||!ball)
    {
        printf("Unable to load a png: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    // centre the bitmap on screen
    SDL_Rect leftr;
    leftr.x = 0;
    leftr.y = (screen->h - left->h) / 2;

    SDL_Rect rightr;
    rightr.x = (screen->w - right->w);
    rightr.y = (screen->h - right->h) / 2;

    SDL_Rect ball1;
    ball1.x = ((screen->w - ball->w) / 2)+50;
    ball1.y = (screen->h - ball->h) / 2;

    SDL_Rect ball2;
    ball2.x = ((screen->w - ball->w) / 2)-50;
    ball2.y = (screen->h - ball->h) / 2;

    bool b1xm=0;//describes ball 1's movement in x
    bool b1ym=0;
    bool b2xm=1;
    bool b2ym=1;

    unsigned short lscore=0;
    unsigned short rscore=0;


    FPSmanager * manex;

    SDL_initFramerate( manex );
    // you want the top framerate to be 60 for example
    SDL_setFramerate( manex, 60 );

    // program main loop
    bool done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
                         //this is where my main code is
    } // end main loop

    // free loaded images
    SDL_FreeSurface(left);
    SDL_FreeSurface(right);
    SDL_FreeSurface(ball);

    // all is well
    printf("Exited cleanly\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Question #1: why are you calling SDL_GetKeyState prior to your call to SDL_Init? You should not call ANYTHING else prior to SDL_Init.

Comment: So, what variable are you adding that causes the crash, and where?

Comment: @thedaian the variables lscore and rscore.

Comment: @PlayDeezGames Thanks for the fix! (I'm surprised that didn't cause any problems)

Comment: @PlayDeezGames +1 Do not call stuff like SDK_GetKeyState() in global space and a small FYI that atexit() is not guaranteed to be called in some cases leading to program termination so you may as well add that to your normal program exit flow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing an unallocated pointer (manex) to a function that is expecting it to be allocated. In debug mode, you are passing (IIRC) the value 0xCDCDCDCD. In release, you are passing it a mystery value.

Take out the * between FPSmanager and manex, like so, and use the addressof operator:

```
FPSmanager manex = {0};
SDL_initFramerate(&manex);
SDL_setFramerate(&manex,60);
```

Chances are this is your actual problem, the other issue of variables perhaps just masking it.

Also, as I commented above, *DO NOT* call *ANY* other SDL function prior to your call to SDL_Init.  You've been warned.

Comment: That {0} notation is new to me, except when used as an array initializer, which doesn't seem to be the case. Could you explain?

Comment: you can use it to zero out the memory of a struct, making it unnecessary to do a memset.

Comment: Specifically, it either initializes the first and only member of the struct to 0 or (if there are more members), initializes the first and value-initializes the remainder. Value initialization either calls the default ctor for the initialized type, zero-initializes the type, or value-initializes all elements (if the type is an array). This is covered in 8.5 of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

```
Uint8 *keystates = SDL_GetKeyState( NULL );
```

This is initialized at startup, even before your main() is called, thus it is called before SDL_Init.

Change it to:

```
Uint8 *keystates = 0;
```

and later on, in main() After the SDL_Init;

```
keystates = SDL_GetKeyState( NULL );
```